# How can i gracefully shutdown siebel application object manager

Tags: crm, siebel

My Requirement is to gracefully shutdown siebel applicaiton object manager component having more then 100 tasks to complete. i try with shutdown SCBroker but faced weird issue while navigating application.
BR

Answer (score 1):

SCBroker manages connections between SWSE and Siebel Server, to shutdown an AOM you can run:

```
shutdown comp <comp_name> for server <server_name>
```

or:

```
shutdown fast comp <comp_name> for server <server_name>
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/SystAdm/SystAdm_SrvrMgrCLI15.html

Answer (score 0):

**Graceful stop (wait for all tasks to complete):**
shutdown comp <comp_name> for server <server_name>

**Forced stop :**
shutdown fast comp <comp_name> for server <server_name>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).